# Distributed Transaction hanging on update sql server

Tags: sql-server, transactions, distributed

I'm updating 4 different records on 2 different servers. My issue is the distributed transaction always hangs and results in a timeout when I run the query if I run one of the updates. I'm a bit new to locking transactions, so having a hard time figuring out a way around this.

Here's some psuedocode since I can't show it.

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @RecordID INT;
    SELECT @RecordID=ID FROM [RemoteServer].[CompanyData].[dbo].[OldRecords] WHERE CustomerNumber=@CustomerNumber AND ReportID=@ReportID;

    IF @RecordID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        /* This is the offending update*/
        UPDATE [RemoteServer].[CompanyData].[dbo].[OldRecordInfo] SET /* bunch of parameters here */ WHERE RecordID=@RecordID;
        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RETURN;
        END

        /* This one works fine */
                UPDATE [RemoteServer].[CompanyData].[dbo].[OldRecords] SET /* bunch of parameters here */ WHERE RecordID=@RecordID;
        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RETURN;
        END
    END


 /* Do some more stuff */
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Any call to update the OldRecordInfo table will cause the whole process to hang. It isn't referenced in any other table but OldRecords ID is a Primary Key & Foreign Key for OldRecordsInfo so that both records have the same ID. If I comment out the update to oldrecords update it still fails. There is no triggers on the update either. I'm thinking it has something to do with foreign key constraints and locking, but I'm a bit unsure of how to handle that. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Edit:
So I was able to get it to work quickly by adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) to the offending statement. Before hand I'd let it run for 20 minutes and it hadn't finished. It is a single update query with 35 parameters.

Comment: I always try to do DML on the local server, rather than through the remote, when using linked servers. Can you move the data locally and then update?

Comment: That's the end goal (what the team wants), but unfortunately there are a large number of legacy apps (from 1995-today) that use these tables from back when the company didn't have good coding standards. So we are moving to a more modern architecture for this application, but we need to keep things in sync until we are sure we've caught all the loose ends. So rush job to get product out the door for the initial release then ween all the old code off over the next 3-4 months.

OPTION(RECOMPILE) fixed my issue for some reason, hadn't had to do that before.